# LinkedIn python api getting updates

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to get company updates from linkedin using the python api. I tried to get more than 10 updates, but I only get 10, no less, no more. please see if my code is wrong:

```
CONSUMER_KEY = '9puxXXXXXXXX'     # This is api_key
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'brtXoXXXXXXXXXXX'   # This is secret_key

USER_TOKEN = '802b1348-XXXXXXXX'   # This is oauth_token
USER_SECRET = 'e7a0c3XXXXXXXXXXX'   # This is oauth_secret
RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                                                      USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET, 
                                                      RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
d = application.get_company_updates(1035, params={'count': 26})
print d['_count']

>>> 
10
>>>
```

I also tried

```
d = application.get_company_updates(1035, params={'_count': 26})
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Trying `params={'_count': 26}` blindly has no point here since `count` is clearly a URL query string as documented http://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-shares. Seeing how python-linkedin uses the `requests` library to perform the actual communication with the APIs, why don't you either A) raise an issue on https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/issues or B) work with `requests` and some OAuth library to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: @woozyking I have no idea what any of that means. I am just copying and pasting

Comment: Choose A) raise an issue on github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/issues if you're just copying and pasting. And with that type of mindset, you're not going to learn much here at Stack Overflow, just my 2 cents :)

Comment: @woozyking that's exactly what I did. Thanks. Also, I'm trying to learn by example. I just was given 1 or 2 lines of examples with twitter and facebook api and I got tremendous amounts of things done. I just have so many issues and misguidance with linkedin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from linkedin employee:

> Unfortunately posts have a "expiration" date which after a while they
>   no longer 
>       are turned by the API. The exact expiration date is in flux at the moment. The 
>       reason for that is to give the API users a "snapshop" view of the company instead 
>       of a lifetime view, thus keeping applications light and agile.
>
> Thanks,
>      Lee